# ESP-201 reboots every now and then if mounted in a breadboard

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'm experimenting with this device and I'm having trouble when I mount it to a breadboard. It is working for some time, then restarts sporadically. Sometimes it's a few minutes, sometimes it's hours.

I'm using the current integer master NodeMCU firmware built with the default modules + the onewire module.

The parts I'm using:

- ESP-201
- a 170 point breadboard
- CP2102 USB to TTL converter
- LM1117T voltage regulator
- 1000 µF 16V capacitor

I bent the front pins so that the ESP-201 fits into the breadboard ( https://flic.kr/p/GzCp4k )

The wiring:

- CP2102 5v ---- LM1117T 5v
- ESP-201 EN ---- 3V3
- ESP-201 IO15 ---- GND
- Capacitor between GND and 3V3

Plus all GNDs and 3V3s connected. For uploading the program, I've connected the 4 front pins to GND, 3V3, RX and TX to GND, 3V3, TX and RX, respectively. I've removed these wires afterwards.

An image of my config: https://flic.kr/p/GbiPBE .

### Reproduction

You'll need a ThingSpeak channel to inspect the restarts. Create one and note the Write Key.

You can use the following simple program to test (just fill in the WIFI SSID, PASSWORD, and the WRITE_KEY):

```
local WIFI_SSID = "..."
local WIFI_PASSWORD = "..."
local WRITE_KEY = "..."

tmr.alarm(0, 5000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function()
    wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
    wifi.sta.config(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD)

    tmr.alarm(1, 60000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function()
        print("Doing something...")
    end)

    local connout = nil
    connout = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

    connout:on("receive", function(connout, payloadout)
    if (string.find(payloadout, "Status: 200 OK") ~= nil) then
        print("Posted OK");
    end
    end)

    connout:on("connection", function(connout, payloadout)

    connout:send("GET /update?api_key="..WRITE_KEY.."&field1=1"
    .. " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    .. "Host: api.thingspeak.com\r\n"
    .. "Connection: close\r\n"
    .. "Accept: */*\r\n"
    .. "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n"
    .. "\r\n")
    end)

    connout:on("disconnection", function(connout, payloadout)
    connout:close();
    collectgarbage();
    end)

    connout:connect(80,'api.thingspeak.com')
end)
```

It simply logs when the device is started (or restarted) and also starts a timer so that the device can not sleep. Save it as init.lua, so that it is started when the device is restarted.

Power up the device, and let it run for a while. You should see restarts every now and then:

[image: ThingSpeak Chart]

If the device is out of the breadboard, it works without restarting.

P.S.: I've also posted this question to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/4gcrru/esp_201_occasional_reboots_if_mounted_to_a/)

Comment: That's a whole lot of wiring just to run a temp sensor... Is this based on NodeMCU or Arduino -> add the respective tag? In my early ESP8266 days I also played with a 201 but whenever it rebooted it was my fault.

Comment: I've added the tag, it's NodeMCU. But I don't think it would matter, but who knows.

Comment: If you don't show us a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE) then you're right...it wouldn't matter much.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I assemble a reproducible example and I'll update my question

Comment: Oh, and putting an URL behind that Reddit reference might also help.